# Is it possible to start VisualVM immediately with some application?

Tags: java, profiling, visualvm

It is said in documentation, that I should manually find my application in [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) window and "Open" it:

[image]

Can I avoid this step?

For example, to use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) I can run my application with

```
-javaagent:ScenicView.jar
```

and it will start Scenic View automatically.

Can I do the same with VisualVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be the *Eclipse Visual VM Launcher*, when you are starting you application from within the IDE:

https://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html

Another option is to use the "Visual VM Startup Profiler" as explained here:
https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html

Comment: The VisualVM Startup Profiler link is dead

Comment: @Novaterata thanks for pointing that out... changed the link to a more recent resource